# How to run Test Analyze Code Coverage for a specific project in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, code-coverage

Currently in Visual Studio 2012, when getting code coverage of my unit tests, all I can see is the options for `selected tests` and `all tests`

I want to get coverage from one project only. How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 11):

use the "Test Explorer" window to filter the tests by project [image]

- Then you can use `CTRL+A` to select all of the tests.
- Now when you execute "Selected Tests" on the Analyze Code Coverage (or right-click the tests and select "`Analyse coverage for selected tests`"), you will get coverage only for those tests
- When you look in the code coverage results, you will see that `Covered %` will only include non-zero figures for the classes covered by the test.
- afaik there is no way to hide the 0% coverage (i.e non-tested) classes from a project in the results which is a shame as it means you have to sort by Covered% and ignore everything that's 0. So all of the classes from the project(s) that the selected tests reference will be shown but if the selected tests didn't touch them, then the coverage for those will show as 0.